# Should questions saying What is this syntax in X? be renamed to the actual technical term

Tags: discussion, title

There are many questions on SO that contain some syntactical term in the title. Should the syntax be renamed to the actual term of that syntax.

**Example:**

The question [What does two colons inside an angular expression {{::}} mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678400/angular-inside-an-angular-expression) should be renamed to `One-time binding in AngularJS`.

**If renamed**

- Users who don't know what the technical term for the syntax is, it'll be difficult to search for it

**If not**

- It will be difficult to find the questions that contains special characters as search engines will strip them out
- If not, there are chances that the question can be asked again if user know what the technical term is and is not able to search

Comment: like minded people ;), but I agree this is a problem.

Comment: Is there another question with the correct terminology in the title that you can link it to as a duplicate? If so, just close the new question as a duplicate of the old one and leave the title the same. That way both groups of people (those who know the correct terminology and those who don't) will be able to find the original question in the future.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Well, that partially answer the question, if having dupe, close it. But what if there is no dupe, then should it be renamed or not?

Comment: It probably should be rewritten to serve as many people as possible. I usually assume that a majority of searchers are going to know the correct term to search for (a perilous assumption, I know), so I would err on the side of getting the question into search engines with the right keywords.

Comment: I don't think beginners would know the term. If they know, most of the times, they won't need SO anyway. Like this one. [Is there a way to substring a string in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string-in-python)

Comment: @Lafexlos Yeah, I might be giving people too much credit. ;)  But still, in cases like that where it's a really common operation that a beginner just doesn't know the name for, odds are very good that there's already a canonical question to link to.

Comment: I think this title should not be rewritten. If you leave it alone, you know that there is at least one person has the question who thinks this is the right thing to search for. If you change it, you know that at least one person who does not need to ask this question thinks this is the right thing to search for.

Comment: a bigger issue is the accepted answer is basically nothing but a link only answer to a blog post instead of the documentation ... but as long as the `{{::}}` is in the title those that need to find it should be able to.

Comment: @Jarrod: Searching by symbols doesn't work in google or on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

I think that titles should be descriptive enough so people can:

1. Figure what the asker is asking without all the baggage
2. Be search friendly.

I've edited the title so that people without the knowledge of the proper terminology knows what is being asked *and* people that knows the terminology can relate.

Comment: I am sure this is a duplicate, you should find a duplicate target and vote to close it as a duplicate as well.

Comment: @Jarrod: Braiam does not have enough rep to close vote yet.